# Simple lookup function

Tags: c#, list, lookup

I've got a simple struct which I want to use as a lookup table:

```
public struct TileTypeSize
{
    public string type;
    public Size size;

    public TileTypeSize(string typeIn, Size sizeIn)
    {
        type = typeIn;
        size = sizeIn;
    }
}
```

I populate this thusly:

```
        tileTypeSizeList.Add(new TileTypeSize("W",rectangleSizeWall));
        tileTypeSizeList.Add(new TileTypeSize("p",rectangleSizePill));
        tileTypeSizeList.Add(new TileTypeSize("P",rectangleSizePowerPill));
        tileTypeSizeList.Add(new TileTypeSize("_",rectangleSizeWall));
        tileTypeSizeList.Add(new TileTypeSize("=",rectangleSizeWall));
```

What is the most efficient way to look up the size for a given type?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ Cast Enumerable to List of specific type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998841/linq-cast-enumerable-to-list-of-specific-type)

Comment: If that is all your struct contains why not use a Dictionary?

Comment: Though the accepted answer is spot-on, if you had to go with the `struct`, really, REALLY make sure it's not mutable (as you have it presently). Mutable `struct` semantics are quite evil. The solution: make those fields `private readonly` instead of `public` and put properties with `get` accessors only for each field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In general**, the most efficient way would be to put your data into a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) or similar container instead ([`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) and [`SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.Generic.aspx) have small differences from `Dictionary` and are an even better fit in certain cases):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Size>
{
     { "W", rectangleSizeWall },
     // etc
}
```

And then:

```
var size = dict["W"];
```

You can of course still iterate sequentially over the values in the dictionary if there is reason to do so.

**If 5 types is all you are going to be looking up** (i.e. the size of the problem is ridiculously small) then a straight list like you have would likely be faster than an associative container. So:

```
var tileStruct = tileTypeSizeList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.type == "W");
if (tileStruct.type == "") {
    // not found
}
else {
    var size = tileStruct.size;
}
```

You may remove the "if found" check if you are sure that you will never have a search miss.

Comment: Excellent - using a dictionary is the way to go. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If you know there will be one and only one match in the collection, then you can use:

```
var size = tileTypeSizeList.Single(t => t.type == someType).size;
```

If not, you'll have to be a little more clever to properly handle the cases where no match is found:

```
Size size;
var match = 
    tileTypeSizeList
        .Cast<TileTypeSize?>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.type == someType);
if(match != null) size = match.size;
```

Keep in mind, though, that there are better ways to store this information if that is the only data in the struct. I would suggest a `Dictionary<string, Size>`.

Comment: Use `Single()` or `SingleOrDefault()` - It's semantically more accurate

Comment: @Basic - That assumes that there is only one match in the list. Nowhere has the OP said that the name is unique.

Comment: I inferred it from `look up _the_ size for a given type` but I agree it's ambiguous

Comment: `First` will throw exception if no element found

Comment: Nitpick: `TileTypeSize` is a value type, so the null check won't work.

Comment: @Jon - Fixed that as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
var type = tileTypeSizeList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.type == someType);
if(type==null) throw new NotFoundException();
return type.size;
```

But if the list is big and you need to lookup data really often you better use `Dictionary` as noticed in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Dictionary instead of a List:

```
Dictionary<string, TileTypeSize> tileTypeSizeDictionary = Dictionary<string, TileTypeSize>();
tileTypeSizeDictionary.Add("W", new TileTypeSize("W",rectangleSizeWall));
...
```

You lookup your elements with:

```
  TileTypeSize rectangleSizeWall = tileTypeSizeDictionary["W"];
```

A dictionary is faster than a list when you need to lookup by key.

Comment: This is much simpler and more closely matches my needs. Cheers